# Populate a repeated custom protocol buffer field in in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

How do I populate a repeated custom protocol buffer field in in C++?

Example protocol buffer:

```
package protocol;
import "enumerations.proto";
option optimize_for=SPEED;

message UserCommandProtocol {
  required uint64 utcTime=1;
  required uint64 playerId=2;
  optional int32 targetId=3;
  optional int32 number=4;

  message pair {
      required float first = 1;
      required float second = 2;
  }

  repeated uint64 bucketId=5 [packed=true]; 
  repeated pair points=6;
  repeated pair backupPoints=7;

  required COMMANDS command=8;
  optional Type type=9;
  optional Orientation orientation=10;
  optional COMMANDS_PRIORITY priority=11;
}
```

I only have a problem with populating points. In my code, I have an object `std::list<std::pair<float,float>> p`, and I want to copy those values to `UserCommandProtocol points`.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over your list of pairs adding each of them.

```
UserCommandProtocol user_command;

// then, iterate over the list... for each element of the list do:

    std::list<std::pair<float,float>>::iterator it = ...; 

    pair* added_pair = user_command.add_points();
    added_pair->set_first(it->first);
    added_pair->set_second(it->second);
```

You may want to read the section [Fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#fields) (specially the subsection *Repeated Embedded Message Fields*) of Protocol Buffers' documentation.